# NSJsonSerialzation not parsing results from Facebook - Cocoa error 3840

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm authenticating with Facebook on my iOS application and use following method to grab the feed.
When I check if it is valid JSON object, it returns true, but if I attempt to parse it, it gives me error:

```
Mistake: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)
```

What can be done about that? Here is what is arriving from server, perfectly valid JSON - http://pastebin.com/ZwTnvi5g (got it by NSLog the result).

How do I fix it so the nsjsonserialization parses it correctly?

```
- (void) refreshButtonPressed
{
    FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/feed"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        NSError *mistake;

        BOOL can = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:result];

        NSLog(@"%d", can);


        NSDictionary *first = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&mistake];

        if (mistake) {
            NSLog(@"Mistake: %@", [mistake localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Show us some actual JSON, not, as you put it, the `NSLog()` of a massive dictionary.

Comment: @CodaFi - this is the NSLog of id result that this completion handler gets and which fails to convert. I don't know how to get anything better than that..

Comment: @CodaFi it prints the text I provided on pastebin, that's it, I haven't cut anything or added anything

Comment: @Dvole If that's the JSON you've got, then it isn't valid at all.  Run it through a JSON linter, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually reading documentation could have helped here.

```
 @param result          The result of the request.  This is a translation of
                        JSON data to `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` objects.  This
                        is nil if there was an error.
```

It parses everything itself, I don't even need to do that. So it returns valid NSDictionary or NSArray.