# Manipulating Facebook/JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to handle Facebook JSON data and transform it into a NSMutable Dictionary, but I'm getting (null) when I try to print the data. Although when I try to do a count, I get a number.

User_likes is NSMutableDictionary which is globally defined. I'm getting (null) on this line:

```
NSLog(@"User likes: %@", user_likes);
```

This is my code:

```
NSString *query =
 @"SELECT page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me() ";
 // Set up the query parameter
 NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
 // Make the API request that uses FQL
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
 parameters:queryParam
 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
 id results,
 NSError *error) {
 if (error) {
 NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 } else {

 user_likes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:results options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 NSLog(@"User likes: %@", user_likes);

 NSInteger* n_user_likes = [results count];
 NSInteger* n_user_likes2 = [user_likes count];

 NSLog(@"n user likes %qi", n_user_likes);
 NSLog(@"n user likes2 %qi", n_user_likes2);

 id val = nil;
 id values = [[user_likes allKeys] objectAtIndex:0 ];
 NSLog(@"values id %@", values);
```

When I print results, I get a lot of data from Facebook, this is a sample of it:

```
data =     (
                {
            "page_id" = 253370381511811;
            type = "PUBLIC FIGURE";
        },
                {
            "page_id" = 148389618201;
            type = "LOCAL BUSINESS";
        },
                {
            "page_id" = 213631462169238;
            type = COMMUNITY;
        },
                {
            "page_id" = 162297750451425;
            type = "NON-PROFIT ORGANIZATION";
        },
                {
            "page_id" = 503620106320217;
            type = "MEDIA/NEWS/PUBLISHING";
        },
```

Comment: Is results `null`? Should result be a JSON/NSArray?

Comment: yes, please try print results and tell us what is happening

Comment: Yes, I changed my question. results prints a lot of Facebook data in JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do directly

```
user_likes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:results options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

you need first create a dictionary with the data in `results` like this:

```
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:results]; 
    user_likes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[dictionary objectForKey:@"value_of_the_likes"] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",user_likes);
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
```

**EDIT:**

Please, create this class to your project and import in the class where you need use this.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (JSONExtensions)

+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithJSONData:(NSData*)data;
-(NSData*)JSONValue;
-(NSString*)JSONString;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary(JSONExtensions)

+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithJSONData:(NSData*)data{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
        return nil;
    };
    return result;
}

-(NSData*)JSONValue{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
        return nil;
    };

    return result;
}

-(NSString*)JSONString{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.JSONValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I'm getting "No known class method for selector 'dictionaryWithJSONData:'"

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0xb949070 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}" when I try to run the line with dictionaryWithJSONData

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forget set up options:

```
NSJSONReadingOptions options = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves;

user_likes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:results options:options error:&error];
```

i hope this be useful for you!

**UPDATE:**

Check this :
[NSJsonSerialzation not parsing results from Facebook - Cocoa error 3840](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956115/nsjsonserialzation-not-parsing-results-from-facebook-cocoa-error-3840)

Let me know if that helps you!

Comment: I'm getting this error to, but the solution provided in the question doesn't work for me